# Как с CASE проверить условие по значениям в разных строках?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть такая таблица:

```
|START_DATE   | CLIENT_ID | ACTIVE|
|-------------|-----------|-------|
|06.01.2021   |   33270524|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  436673200|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  125182522|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  127406386|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  127407079|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  127424573|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  128387226|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  128387876|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  128876323|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  128876751|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  129398251|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  132281879|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  132411175|      1|
|06.01.2021   |  132545358|      1|
```

Нужно проверить следующее условие: если у пользователя в дату за прошлый месяц `start_date - 30`  был статус `active = 1`,  а на момент `start_date`  `active = 0`, то присвоить значение 1, иначе - 0.

Как это можно реализовать через `CASE`?

Comment: Ну в case то все просто, `x.active = 1 then ...`. тут вопрос то не в case должен касаться, а построения запроса. надо же этот active прошлого месяца в запись текущего притащить, а значит делать какой то join с записью предыдущего месяца или как то оконными функциями обыгрывать. А для этого решения в вопросе не достаточно информации. Какие даты бывают, какая версия СУБД, что такое в этой таблице "пользователь" и т.п.

Comment: pl/sql developer 12, "пользователь" это уникальные client_id, даты - срез за пол года по каждому дню

Comment: А даты по клиенту могут пропускаться и что делать если пропущено. Ну скажем сегодня 31 января, значит -30 дней это 1 января. И вот как раз на 1е у клиента записи нет, что делаем ? Вообще напрашивается простой join таблицы самой с собой с вот этим условием на совпадение клиента и разницу дат

Comment: Не подскажете, как может выглядеть join с этим условием на разницу дат?

Comment: @Sam324 a) pl/sql developer (правильно PL/SQL Developer ) это не СУБД, а IDE для работы с ней. б) Пожалуйста, замените картинку в вопросе на данные в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На таких данных:

```
 CLIENT_ID START_DATE              ACTIVE
---------- ------------------- ----------
         1 2021-01-30 00:00:00          1
         1 2021-03-01 00:00:00          1
         2 2021-04-03 00:00:00          1
         2 2021-05-03 00:00:00          0
         3 2021-05-27 00:00:00          1
         3 2021-06-28 00:00:00          0
```

Ожидаю, что только клиент 2 имел `active=1` ровно месяц назад.

Так оно и есть (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c87d4b712fb5bda80beb0ea8427c14b9)):

```
select t1.*, 
    case when t1.active = 0 and t2.start_date is not null then 1 else 0 end newactive 
from t t1 
left join t t2 on (
    t2.client_id = t1.client_id and 
    t2.start_date = add_months (t1.start_date, -1));

 CLIENT_ID START_DATE              ACTIVE  NEWACTIVE
---------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
         2 2021-05-03 00:00:00          0          1
         3 2021-05-27 00:00:00          1          0
         1 2021-03-01 00:00:00          1          0
         3 2021-06-28 00:00:00          0          0
         2 2021-04-03 00:00:00          1          0
         1 2021-01-30 00:00:00          1          0
```

---

> если у пользователя в дату за прошлый месяц start_date - 30

Замените в запросе выше `add_months` на `t1.start_date-30`, если действительно в месяце всегда 30 дней.